# widgetlogic and permalinks

Tags: widgets, permalinks

I'm trying to use widgetlogic to conditionally display menus on certain pages. Each menu uses a tag like `is_page(array("Page Name", "Page Name 2" ...))`, and works perfectly until I try to change permalinks (whereupon all the menus disappear from their respective pages).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing permalinks should have absolutely no affect whatsoever on the parameters passed to [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page). Are you perhaps changing the **Page Titles** instead?

Regardless, try passing the **Page ID** instead of the **Page Title** to your `is_page()` array.

Comment: I was actually about to post a similar answer myself, having gotten it to work in the meantime. Passing either page IDs or page slugs to `is_page` works fine (initially, I was passing page names). No titles changed, the only thing I changed to get from "working fine" to "no dice" was the permalink format. Thanks for your help.